# grapgql resolvers: fields with types that refer each other

Tags: recursion, nested, graphql, apollo-server

I've got this schema and I'm implementing it in apollo-graphql and have challenges writing resolvers for types with subtypes that refer each other as follows.

My schema

```
type Period {
    start: DateTime!
    end: DateTime!
...
    equipment: [Equipment]
    events: [Event]
}

type Equipment {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    model: Model!
    loads: [Load]
    events: [Event] <<<<
}

type Event {
    id: ID!
    start: DateTime!
    end: DateTime!
    duration: Duration!
    status: Status!
    equipment: Equipment! <<<<
}
```

This would typically lead to a query such as

```
{
period (start:"2019-12-01 07:00:00" end:"2019-12-01 19:00:00")
  {
  equipment {
     id
     events {
         id
         status
         equipment {
            id
            events {
              ....
            }
         }  

     }
  }

}
```

From the point of the returned objects this should be:

```
Period : is bound by a start and end.
Period.equipment : is all equipment used during that period.
period.equipment.events : would be all events in that period that relate to a this equipment
period.equipment.events.equipment : would be equipment that relate to these events.

... so on and so forth.
```

In essence this leads to a series of filtering that needs to be passed down based on period, equipment and events.

It seems to make sense for the business domain but I'm having trouble writing resolvers that pass down these filter params.

One approach I can think of is to ...
a query resolver for `period` return a `equipmentId` and `eventId` and have type resolvers for `equipment` and `events

```
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
     ...
        period: (_, { start, end }, { dataSources }) =>
            dataSources.Data.getPeriod({
                start: start,
                end: end
            }),
```

and then have type resolvers for `Equipment` and `Events`

```
    Equipment: {
...

        events: (equipment, { }, { dataSources }) => {
        // How can I get start,end values here?

//      code to return events
        },
```

but then how do I pass filter variables `start`, `end` etc to these types?

If I try to resolve `period.equiment` as a field resolver then I need to satisfy an infinite level of recursion as `period.equipment.events.equipment.events ....` right?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can 'attach' parameters to resolved/returned object (in period) ... it will be accessible by 'child' resolvers by parent (1st resolver arg) ... search for 'circular graphql'

Comment: I don't think there is no need to pass down the filters at all in this case. If you return a Period that meets certain constraints (for example, the start and end times), then any Equipment related to that period will already be constrained *through* their relationship to that Period. Similarly, if that Equipment has Events, you would only be returning Events related to the Equipment, which is related to the Period. You would never return Events for a Period that didn't meet the start and end filters because then those relationships wouldn't exist. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi @DanielReaden, 

Unfortauntely that is not true.

While 'any Equipment related to that period will already be constrained through their relationship to that Period' is true,

` Events related to the Equipment,` are all events related to that Equipment and are not constrained to the original period,

Hence my need to pass down the period start,end to the grandchild level